# How can I rely on gRPC's flow control features when making async calls?

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

Is it possible for a Python gRPC client to asynchronously make simple unary calls (i.e. not streaming calls) to a server as fast as the server can service them but block if an async request can't be written into the client's outgoing connection due to back pressure?

There's very little documentation on the flow control features of the gRPC implementation.

Simply creating a call future doesn't seem to block ever.